# Minimum Age Verification GUI C#

Tags: c#, validation, user-interface

i am trying to verify that a customer is at least 25, in order to rent a car.
I believe i have the right code to calculate age in my customer class, but it is not actually verifying it in my code for applying

Code from customer.cs

```
 public int Age
    {
        get
        {
            // Get today's date
            DateTime currDate = DateTime.Now;

            // Get the difference in years
            int age = currDate.Year - birthdayPicker.Year;

            // Subtract another year if we're before the
            // birth day in the current year
            if (currDate.Month < birthdayPicker.Month || (currDate.Month == birthdayPicker.Month && currDate.Day < birthdayPicker.Day))
                age--;

            return age;
        }
    }
```

Code From form1.cs (still working on the apply button, but trying to verify age before i move on)

```
private void applyButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (myCust.Age >= (25))
        {
            maketextbox.Text = myVehicle.Make;
            modelTextbox.Text = myVehicle.Model;
            yearTextbox.Text = Convert.ToString(myVehicle.Year);
            vinTextbox.Text = Convert.ToString(myVehicle.Vin);
            MessageBox.Show("Congratulations, you have been approved to rent a car!");
        }

        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You are not old enough to rent a car.");
        }
```

Comment: Why you compare against a negative value? the Age property returns a positive value (unless the DateTimePicker is allowed to be Greater thant today)

Comment: that was a typo in my code, had already fixed that back.

Comment: Then what do you mean with `but it is not actually verifying it` ?

Comment: it should be calucalting age, then checking to see if they are at least 25, but when the program runs, it doesnt seem to be checking the age, it thinks they are 25 or older, and outputs rental info

Comment: Well, this could be solved using the debugger and setting a breakpoint inside the code of the property. Then check the values of the birthDayPicker.

Comment: By the way, how do you pass the birthDayPicker inside that class?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe an error in your comparison code:

```
 // Subtract another year if we're before the
 // birth day in the current year
 if (currDate.Month < birthdayPicker.Month || (currDate.Month >= birthdayPicker.Month && currDate.Day < birthdayPicker.Day))
            age--;
```

Note:  **==**  operator changed to  **>=**